# AngularJs - Cancel route navigation on rejected promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ngroute

I'm working on a project which consists of multiple routes.

While navigating from one route to another I'm using resolve to fetch the data from the server.

In case of resolved promise it is navigating successfully however if the promise is rejected it is going to the the specified route and it is firing $routeChangeError that is not what I expected.

Now I'm trying to cancel the route if the promise is rejected means I want to stay in the current page if the promise is rejected.

How can I do it? Any Ideas or am I not thinking in correct way?

Comment: you need to listen to the $routeChangeError event and redirect to previous page/state from here. This will be your best option.

Comment: I did think the option you've specified however here we're actually navigating to route and again navigating back (route1->route2->route1).

Comment: If you want to use the "resolve" feature of a route, this will be your only way. Other approach will be to go around will $locationChangeStart and $routeChangeStart events

Comment: @PierreGayvallet Thank you for the suggestions, I will definitely look into that :)